# New Line on Django admin Text Field

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I am trying to create a blog o  django where the admin posts blogs from the admin site.
I have given a TextField for the content and now want to give a new line.
I have tried using \n but it doesn't help. The output on the main html page is still the same with \n printing in it. I have also tried the 
 tag and allowed tags=True in my models file. Still the same. All the tags are coming as it is on the html page.

My Django admin form submitted:
[image: Screenshot of the admin page]

The result displayed in my public template:
[image: Screenshot of a template, showing text without any newlines]

Comment: Can anyone help me I am having same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching the internet and trying different [Django Template Filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/), I came across one specific filter, **SAFE**.

For me, **LINEBREAKS** filter didn't work, as provided by @Maxime above, but *safe* did.

Use it like this in your html template file.

```
{{post.content|safe}}
```

To have a better understanding of **SAFE** filter, i suggest reading the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/).

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [template filter `linebreaks`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks), that will convert the *reals* \n (that means the newline in the textarea, not the ones you typed using `\` then `n`) into `<br />`:

```
{{ post.content|linebreaks }}
```

Alternatively, you can use `linebreaksbr` if you don't want to have the surrounding `<p>` block of course.

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for the same, I have a model with text field and also corresponding admin class, I have no clue where to put this ??? do we need to override the html and create a template for it???

Comment: @lokesh1729 ,try using safe keyword in html template file like this:

{{ post.content|safe }}

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{post.content|linebreaks}}
```

This will make the line in the textbox appear as it is without using `\n` or `\`.

Answer (score 0):

`{{post.content|linebreaksbr}}`

Besides the newline function in your CSS Declaration will work too.